# How to know what this regex represents

Tags: java, regex

I am maintaining some code and I see a regular expression like `someString.matches("\\$\\{.*}")` 
 I know back slashes in java are escaping the back slash. $ means end of line and the expression within {} means the string thats expected. 
 So I believe (though now I know I am wrong) that this regex is filtering strings which have dots in the end of the string and are in this format :  `It seems to be.a.beautiful.day` But  I am wrong. Can some one please point me to understanding what really this regex can parse ?

Comment: Perhaps you could paste it into an [explainer](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=\%24\{.*})?

Comment: You can also try http://rubular.com/

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Ooooo, that explainer is nice :)

Comment: I agree. thanks for the explainer @dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backslash character (`\`) is escaping the dollar sign (`$`) and curly brace (`{`) so that they are not treated as special characters, so this regex will match a literal dollar sign followed immediately by a curly brace, followed by any number of any character followed by a closing curly brace(`}`).

Some examples of things this will match:

- ${9.00}
- ${}
- ${{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}
- ${}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}

Comment: Thank you, this explains it the best to me.

Answer (score 2):

Java compiler takes this string `"\\$\\{.*}"` and replaces double slashes with single slashes, so the regexp engine sees this:

```
\$\{.*}
```

This means a string that starts in a dollar sign `$` followed by a sequence of zero or more characters in curly braces.

A better way to write a similar expression would be as follows:

```
\$\{[^}]*}
```

(you would need to escape your backslashes for the Java compiler). This expression will stop after seeing the first closing curly brace, and avoid [braktracking](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/greedy-lazy-performance).

Answer (score 1):

```
"\\$\\{.*}"
```

encodes the string

```
\$\{.*}
```

because the Java compiler interprets the `\\` before they get to the regular expression library.

When used as a regular expression it matches a literal `${` followed by any number of non-newline characters until the last literal `}`.